# How do I make this banner look like the Urban Outfitters one?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to practice designing an online shop landing page, and I am taking inspiration from Urban Outfitters. I am trying to get the orange promo part to look the same as Urban Outfitters.

I have tried justify-content: center and space-around, or also using padding but that is not very responsive.

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jinyangzhang/pen/ydaxjM).

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

#promo{
  background-color: #F5C793;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.promo-link{
  color: #222;
  text-decoration-color: #222;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 0.3px solid #d3d3d3;
  min-height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav-links li{
  padding-left: 15px;  
  padding-right: 15px;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #767676;
}

nav a:hover{
  color: #b2b2b2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo{
  color: #30336b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.landing-body{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display:inline;
}

.landing-page{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49% 2% 49%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.three-div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 32% 2% 32% 2% 32%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

img{
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

img:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div id="promo">
  <p>everything you love, all in one place.</p>
  <h3 class="center">MOST ♥ LIKED </h3>
  <p><a href="#" class="promo-link">shop</a></p>
</div>

<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <h2>Giants & Dwarfs</h2>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li id="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="womens"><a href="#">Women's</a></li>
    <li id="mens"><a href="#">Men's</a></li>
    <li id="sale"><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="landing-page">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/q602vtcuu3w3/7rnjSHqBEcgbtJ2pZqZarm/c32a5cbe533a8aab72aee54689ddb7e3/190617-WK3-WGW-4-Update.jpg"></a>
  <a></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/q602vtcuu3w3/6vo26Ry1p3rcvSURCYBoJH/2fdc52ccb0ee69352d8e02ff905d592a/190603-WK1-LGW-1.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="three-div">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/q602vtcuu3w3/7btvNrhUWJrd5UWYSRHtJr/43f9ce8f23d39c839f9b0e34991d97cc/190603-WK1-MGW-5.jpg">
  </a>
  <a></a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/q602vtcuu3w3/5674zBs4G9hFqVyg2ceT6y/83fd495152f58a7bd12e64d68e541dcd/190617-WK3-HGW-7.jpg">
  </a>
  <a></a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/q602vtcuu3w3/3Rz4KD78yXurQYIyqx6oyC/be018c5eeecd2df0a81471bb81177d8d/190617-WK3-WGW-7.jpg">
  </a>
</div>

<div class="exclusives">
  
</div>
```

Trying to replicate [this](https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/), top orange section

Comment: Doesn't look like an ideal use case for flexbox. Try making the 3 elements `display: inline-block` with `margin` for left/right spacing, and `text-align: center` on the parent.

Comment: @JonUleis when i tried that the orange was limited to one box size... i'm sorry if the questions are very beginner I am still getting the hang of all this!

Comment: Please include all code necessary to reproduce the issue on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: What is it doing that you don't want it to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a CSS expert by any stretch, but I have played around a bit with it.  Have you tried using the following options?

padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;

margin-left: 1%;

Padding adds space to the left or to the right of your object.  Margin adds space around your object.  Either can be expressed as pixels or percentage.  I have often found percentages to be more reliable for expected output than pixels, but again, I am not an expert so it could be my own unfamiliarity at work there.

For more detail: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp

Hope this helps - happy coding to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use margins with flexbox, pretty  much like `align-self` with much more control.

```css
#promo {
  background-color: #F5C793;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.left {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.right {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="promo">
  <p class="left">everything you love, all in one place.</p>
  <h3 class="center">MOST ♥ LIKED </h3>
  <p class="right"><a href="#" class="promo-link">shop</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Force your inner elements to display as inline block, add some padding to your center element and flip your promo class from flex to block.

in the below example there are 2 new class (sideMe and sideMeCenter) and a mod to your display property in promo

add the classes to the contained promo elements and should be good to go

```css
.sideMe {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px
}
.sideMeCenter {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

#promo{
  background-color: #F5C793;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align:center;
}

.promo-link{
  color: #222;
  text-decoration-color: #222;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 0.3px solid #d3d3d3;
  min-height: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-links{
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav-links li{
  padding-left: 15px;  
  padding-right: 15px;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #767676;
}

nav a:hover{
  color: #b2b2b2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo{
  color: #30336b;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.landing-body{
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display:inline;
}

.landing-page{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49% 2% 49%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.three-div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 32% 2% 32% 2% 32%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

img{
  display: inline;
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

img:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.exclusives-title{
  padding-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
}

.exclusives-title h2{
  font-weight: 100;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.exclusives{
  grid-template-columns: 14% 3.2% 14% 3.2% 14% 3.2% 14% 3.2% 14% 3.2% 14%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="promo">
  <p class ="sideMe">everything you love, all in one place.</p>
  <h3 class="center sideMe sideMeCenter">MOST ♥ LIKED </h3>
  <p class="sideMe"><a href="#" class="promo-link">shop</a></p>
</div>
```